# How to find inverse of Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've got a query to find enrolled students in a particular activity. On the User model:

```
public function enrolledStudents($activity)
{ 
    $students = $activity->students()
        ->wherePivot('user_id', $this->id)
        ->get();
    return $students;
}
```

Where the Activity model's `students` method is this:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Student', 'activity_student', 'activity_id', 'student_id')
        ->withPivot('user_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

I want another method to find the students who *aren't* enrolled in this activity - how could I go about this?

I.e. $user->students()->notEnrolled($activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you'd have to come from the `Student` angle. Something like this:

```
$students = Student::whereDoesntHave('activities', function($q) use ($activity){
    $q->where('activity_id', $activity->id);
})->get();
```

Note that this method is quite new, so you might need to update Laravel with `composer udpate`